# why does my UIView background distort when segued to next view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, background

I have a background image and a visual blur effect layer on top of that image placed behind all the Views in my storyboard. Whenever I segue to the next view, my background does this sort of gyrating/quivering gesture distorting it for a second, then returns to its regular state. This only happens when I segue to a new view, not when I go back to previous views. Does anybody know why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

`UIVisualEffectView` does not like being animated or it's opacity being changed. I believe it has to do with its optimizations for blur efficiency. Try setting the layer's `shouldRasterize` property.

Comment: how do i set that setting programmatically? because I do see it ass an option when I user the dot syntax

Comment: `view.layer.shouldRasterize = true`

Comment: should i set it to the view itself ( meaning self) or to the VisualEffectView?

Comment: The view itself I think